# Show only the three chars after - in php

Tags: php

So i have reference numbers that look like this:

```
-76527921
O-2323232323
BPP-76527921
EEFS-23232323
```

I wish to output the three numbers after the -.

So in the first case it should output 765 and second 232 etc..

I have tried:

```
echo substr($ref["refno"], 3, 3);
```

But since the prefix (the BPP, O, EEFS or none in this example)  is custom and can be more/less than three chars, it does not work right.

How can i do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `strpos()` to locate the first occurrence of `-` and add 3 to that for your `substr()`.

```
if (!strpos(trim($ref['refno'], '-'), '-')) echo substr(trim($ref['refno'],'-'), 0,3);
else echo substr($ref['refno'], strpos($ref['refno'], '-')+1, 3);
```

Comment: Not right, -91130755 shows as: 130755. I would like it to show as: 911

Comment: Ugh, so much confusion by me. Current version is working as it should.

Answer (score 2):

my solution:

```
echo substr(end(explode("-",$ref['refno'],2)), 0, 3);
```

use `explode()` to make an array ('EEFS','23232323'), then select last part using `end()`, finally substract 3 chars using `substr()`